# MSVC accepts constant pointer to int initialized with nullptr as constant expression

Tags: c++, pointers, language-lawyer, compile-time-constant, constant-expression

After reading about constant expressions I wrote the following example that compiles with msvc but is rejected by both gcc and clang.

```
int *const ptr2 = nullptr;  
static_assert(!ptr2); //msvc passes but both gcc and clang rejects/fails this  

int main()
{
    
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Tsxhxa48r)

As we can see the gcc rejects the code saying:

```
<source>:2:15: error: non-constant condition for static assertion
    2 | static_assert(!ptr2); //msvc passes but both gcc and clang rejects/fails this
      |               ^~~~~
<source>:2:15: error: the value of 'ptr2' is not usable in a constant expression
<source>:1:12: note: 'ptr2' was not declared 'constexpr'
```

On the other hand msvc accepts/compiles the program. I want to know which compiler is correct according to the C++ standard.

---

Note that I am aware that I can use `constexpr` kewyord and the program will compiler with all compilers then. But my question is about the behavior of the current program as per the c++ standard. Also note that I am using C++20.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that msvc is wrong, the other compilers are right.

Comment: There's a rule that const integral variables (and also references) with constexpr initializers are implicitly constexpr. Maybe MSVC thinks it extends to pointers too. But I don't know where to look in the standard.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Maybe https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#3

Comment: @BenVoigt Aha! MSVC is wrong then.

Comment: So basically because `ptr2` isn't potentially constant and so it cannot be used in constant expression context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operand of `!` is contextually converted to `bool` per [[expr.unary.op]/9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.unary.op#9).

Applying [[conv.general]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/conv#general-4) this means we obtain a `bool` value as if by initializing a variable `_` with

```
bool _(ptr2);
```

Per [[dcl.init.general]/16.9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.init#general-16.9) a standard conversion sequence is used to convert the initializer expression `ptr2` to `bool`.

In order to construct that sequence, an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is needed, because the standard conversions to `bool` all require prvalues (see [conv]), but `ptr2` is a lvalue expression.

The lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is not permitted in constant expressions per [[expr.const]/5.8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#5.8), because the lifetime of `ptr2` didn't start during the constant expression evaluation, nor is it *usable in constant expressions*, which is only possible for `constexpr` variables and `const`-qualified integral/enumeration type variables (see [[expr.const]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#4) together with [[expr.const]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#3))

So MSVC is [incorrect](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MSVC-accepts-constant-pointer-to-int-ini/10500157) and the other compilers are correct. The initialization of `ptr2` doesn't matter.

However, if the type of the variable itself was `std::nullptr_t`, then [[dcl.init.general]/16.8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.init#general-16.8)) would preempt 16.7. and the value of the `bool` would `false` without any conversion being applied. In that case, it would be a constant expression.